# If $f(x)=\sin(x)f'(x)$, find the type of $f$

Tags: real-analysis

> If $$ f: [0,π] \rightarrow \mathbb R$$ and
>   $$ f(x)=\sin(x)f'(x) $$ find the the type of $f$.

The solution is: $f$ is a continuous function on $[0,π]$ and differentiable on $(0,π)$, where it will have a minimum value $m$ and a maximum value $M$. The minimum and maximum values ($m$ and $M$) are located where $f$ has an extremality or $ \exists x_{0}\in (0,π)$ such that $ f'(x_{0})=0$ (Fermat's Theorem). Now, for  $$ x=0 \Rightarrow f(0)=0$$
$$x=π \Rightarrow f(π)=0 $$
$$x= x_{0} \Rightarrow f(x_{0})=0$$

So $f$ is the constant null function. Is there another way to prove this, for example, using antiderivative or the constant function theorem?

Comment: Well, $f(x)=\exp\left(\int_0^xdt/\sin(t)\right)$ doesn't seem to be constant to me ...

Comment: The solution of $f(x)=\sin(x) f'(x)$ is $f(x)=C \tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$. Then ...

Comment: What does "the type of $f$" mean?